# Codeigniter - how return array number to controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I need to pass variable $m to the results back to my controller to display in my view.

**Model**

```
  for($i=1; $i<=12;)
{
 $month=array("","01","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
$m = $month[$i];            
$i++;
 $query2=$this->db->query("
    SELECT 
      COUNT(*) AS rr 
    FROM
      trans_email 
    WHERE lup LIKE '2014-$m%' 
    ");
$resultarray[$i]=$query2->result();
foreach($resultarray[$i] as $row)
        {
          $data[$i] = $row;

        }


}
      return array('data'=> $data,
        'count'=> $m);
```

when i return $m to controller, result $m **always 12**

**Controller**

```
$ind = $this->dash_model->monthreport();
$data= array();
 $data['mont'] = $ind['count'];
$data['mont'] = $ind['data'];
$this->parser->parse('blank.htm', $data);
```

**how return $m with value 1,2,3...12**

```
month 01= 1
month 02= 0
month 03= 5
...
month 12 = 0
```

---

Update
i just try code

```
$month=array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
$m =implode(',',$month);// $m = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12";
return array('data'=> $data,
count'=> $m);
```

but i get

```
month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 1
month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 0
month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 0
month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 0
month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 0
month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 0
month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 0
month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 0
month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 0
month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 4
month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 9
month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a string try this

```
$month=array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
$m =implode(',',$month);// $m = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12";
return array('data'=> $data,
count'=> $m);
```

or if you want a array

```
$month=array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
$m =$month;
return array('data'=> $data,
count'=> $m);
```

Comment: thank you, it's work, but how i join with $data  and get value $m =$data in view

Comment: please write down the code for print "month ,01,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13 = 1" this

Comment: try this it may work for you 
for($i = 0 ;$i <count($data) ; $i++){
   echo 'month '.($i+1).' = '.$data[$i] ;
}

Answer (score 0):

You are making a big mistake. You do not need to loop. Just do this:

```
$month=array("","01","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
$m = $month;
```

Also if you want to make a large array number with loop, just do this:

```
for($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
   $m[] = $i; // note that I have used [] after m
}
```

Also you can use `range();` please read about it in  PHP Docs.

Your mistake is that you are create $month array in each loop anew. To edit your current code, do the followings:

Put the month array outside the loop, and add a [] to the m. This tells PHP to add a new array element to m.

```
$month=array("","01","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
 for($i=1; $i<=12;)
{

$m[] = $month[$i];            
$i++;
}
```

Comment: i just try like this, but i got this error  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()